# UI5-Custom D3 CHarts

Tags: d3.js, sapui5

I am trying to integrate a D3 Chart in SAPUI5.
I am almost done and while running the app
I am able to see the Custom chart and it is disappearing in a moment.
Could anybody please help me in resolving this issue.

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap/ui/thirdparty/d3");
jQuery.sap.declare("sap.jaysdkCustomD3Chartings.RadarChart");
sap.ui.core.Control.extend("sap.jaysdkCustomD3Chartings.RadarChart", {

metadata: {
    properties: {
        "axis": {
            type: "string",
            group: "Misc",
            defaultValue: null
        },
        "value": {
            type: "string",
            group: "Misc",
            defaultValue: null
        }
    }
},

init: function() {

    console.log("sap.jaysdkCustomD3Chartings..RadarChart.init()");
    this.sParentId = "";

},
createRadars: function() {
    /*
     * Called from renderer
     */
    debugger;
    console.log("sap.jaysdkCustomD3Chartings.HeatMap.createHeatMap()");
    //  var oRadarLayout = new sap.m.VBox({alignItems:sap.m.FlexAlignItems.Center,justifyContent:sap.m.FlexJustifyContent.Center});
    //var ccRadarHolder = new sap.m.FlexBox("radarHolder", {"alignItems": "Start", "justifyContent": "Center"});
    var ccRadarHolder = new sap.m.VBox("radarHolder", {
        "alignItems": "Start",
        "justifyContent": "Center"
    });
    /* ATTENTION: Important
     * This is where the magic happens: we need a handle for our SVG to attach to. We can get this using .getIdForLabel()
     * Check this in the 'Elements' section of the Chrome Devtools: 
     * By creating the layout and the Flexbox, we create elements specific for this control, and SAPUI5 takes care of 
     * ID naming. With this ID, we can append an SVG tag inside the FlexBox
     */
    this.sParentId = ccRadarHolder.getIdForLabel();
    //  oHeatMapLayout.addItem(oHeatMapFlexBox);

    return ccRadarHolder;

},

/**

* The renderer render calls all the functions which are necessary to create the control,
* then it call the renderer of the vertical layout
* @param oRm {RenderManager}
* @param oControl {Control}
*/

renderer: function(oRm, oControl) {
    var layout = oControl.createRadars();
    oRm.write("<div");
    oRm.writeControlData(layout); // writes the Control ID and enables event handling – important!
    oRm.writeClasses(); // there is no class to write, but this enables
    // support for ColorBoxContainer.addStyleClass(…)
    oRm.write(">");
    oRm.renderControl(layout);
    oRm.addClass('verticalAlignment');
    oRm.write("</div>");
},

onAfterRendering: function() {
    var d = [];
    d = this.getModel().oData;
    var cfg = {
        radius: 5,
        w: 600,
        h: 600,
        factor: 1,
        factorLegend: .85,
        levels: 3,
        maxValue: 0,
        radians: 2 * Math.PI,
        opacityArea: 0.5,
        ToRight: 5,
        TranslateX: 80,
        TranslateY: 30,
        ExtraWidthX: 100,
        ExtraWidthY: 100,
        color: d3.scale.category10()
    };

    var w = 500,
        h = 500;
    var options = {
        w: w,
        h: h,
        maxValue: 0.6,
        levels: 6,
        ExtraWidthX: 300
    };

    var vis = d3.select("#" + this.sParentId);

    if ('undefined' !== typeof options) {
        for (var i in options) {
            if ('undefined' !== typeof options[i]) {
                cfg[i] = options[i];
            }
        }
    }
    cfg.maxValue = Math.max(cfg.maxValue, d3.max(d, function(i) {
        return d3.max(i.map(function(o) {
            return o.value;
        }))
    }));
    var allAxis = (d[0].map(function(i, j) {
        return i.axis
    }));
    var total = allAxis.length;
    var radius = cfg.factor * Math.min(cfg.w / 2, cfg.h / 2);
    var Format = d3.format('%');
    //d3.svg.remove();//d3.select(vis).select("svg").remove();

    var g = //d3.select(vis)
        vis
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", cfg.w + cfg.ExtraWidthX)
        .attr("height", cfg.h + cfg.ExtraWidthY)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + cfg.TranslateX + "," + cfg.TranslateY + ")");

    var tooltip;

    //Circular segments
    for (var j = 0; j < cfg.levels - 1; j++) {
        var levelFactor = cfg.factor * radius * ((j + 1) / cfg.levels);
        g.selectAll(".levels")
            .data(allAxis)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:line")
            .attr("x1", function(d, i) {
                return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total));
            })
            .attr("y1", function(d, i) {
                return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total));
            })
            .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
                return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.sin((i + 1) * cfg.radians / total));
            })
            .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
                return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.cos((i + 1) * cfg.radians / total));
            })
            .attr("class", "line")
            .style("stroke", "grey")
            .style("stroke-opacity", "0.75")
            .style("stroke-width", "0.3px")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (cfg.w / 2 - levelFactor) + ", " + (cfg.h / 2 - levelFactor) + ")");
    }
    //Text indicating at what % each level is
    for (var j = 0; j < cfg.levels; j++) {
        var levelFactor = cfg.factor * radius * ((j + 1) / cfg.levels);
        g.selectAll(".levels")
            .data([1]) //dummy data
            .enter()
            .append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.sin(0));
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.cos(0));
            })
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .style("font-size", "10px")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (cfg.w / 2 - levelFactor + cfg.ToRight) + ", " + (cfg.h / 2 - levelFactor) + ")")
            .attr("fill", "#737373")
            .text(Format((j + 1) * cfg.maxValue / cfg.levels));
    }

    series = 0;
    var axis = g.selectAll(".axis")
        .data(allAxis)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis");
    axis.append("line")
        .attr("x1", cfg.w / 2)
        .attr("y1", cfg.h / 2)
        .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
            return cfg.w / 2 * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total));
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
            return cfg.h / 2 * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total));
        })
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", "grey")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px");
    axis.append("text")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d
        })
        .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .style("font-size", "11px")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dy", "1.5em")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate(0, -10)"
        })
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return cfg.w / 2 * (1 - cfg.factorLegend * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total)) - 60 * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
            return cfg.h / 2 * (1 - Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total)) - 20 * Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total);
        });

    d.forEach(function(y, x) {
        dataValues = [];
        g.selectAll(".nodes")
            .data(y, function(j, i) {
                dataValues.push([
                    cfg.w / 2 * (1 - (parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0)) / cfg.maxValue) * cfg.factor * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total)),
                    cfg.h / 2 * (1 - (parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0)) / cfg.maxValue) * cfg.factor * Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total))
                ]);
            });
        dataValues.push(dataValues[0]);
        g.selectAll(".area")
            .data([dataValues])
            .enter()
            .append("polygon")
            .attr("class", "radar-chart-serie" + series)
            .style("stroke-width", "2px")
            .style("stroke", cfg.color(series))
            .attr("points", function(d) {
                var str = "";
                for (var pti = 0; pti < d.length; pti++) {
                    str = str + d[pti][0] + "," + d[pti][1] + " ";
                }
                return str;
            })
            .style("fill", function(j, i) {
                return cfg.color(series)
            })
            .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea)
            .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                z = "polygon." + d3.select(this).attr("class");
                g.selectAll("polygon")
                    .transition(200)
                    .style("fill-opacity", 0.1);
                g.selectAll(z)
                    .transition(200)
                    .style("fill-opacity", .7);
            })
            .on('mouseout', function() {
                g.selectAll("polygon")
                    .transition(200)
                    .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
            });
        series++;
    });
    series = 0;
    d.forEach(function(y, x) {
        g.selectAll(".nodes")
            .data(y).enter()
            .append("svg:circle")
            .attr("class", "radar-chart-serie" + series)
            .attr('r', cfg.radius)
            .attr("alt", function(j) {
                return Math.max(j.value, 0)
            })
            .attr("cx", function(j, i) {
                dataValues.push([
                    cfg.w / 2 * (1 - (parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0)) / cfg.maxValue) * cfg.factor * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total)),
                    cfg.h / 2 * (1 - (parseFloat(Math.max(j.value, 0)) / cfg.maxValue) * cfg.factor * Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total))
                ]);
                return cfg.w / 2 * (1 - (Math.max(j.value, 0) / cfg.maxValue) * cfg.factor * Math.sin(i * cfg.radians / total));
            })
            .attr("cy", function(j, i) {
                return cfg.h / 2 * (1 - (Math.max(j.value, 0) / cfg.maxValue) * cfg.factor * Math.cos(i * cfg.radians / total));
            })
            .attr("data-id", function(j) {
                return j.axis;
            })
            .style("fill", cfg.color(series)).style("fill-opacity", .9)
            .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                var newX = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cx')) - 10;
                var newY = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('cy')) - 5;

                tooltip
                    .attr('x', newX)
                    .attr('y', newY)
                    .text(Format(d.value))
                    .transition(200)
                    .style('opacity', 1);

                z = "polygon." + d3.select(this).attr("class");
                g.selectAll("polygon")
                    .transition(200)
                    .style("fill-opacity", 0.1);
                g.selectAll(z)
                    .transition(200)
                    .style("fill-opacity", .7);
            })
            .on('mouseout', function() {
                tooltip
                    .transition(200)
                    .style('opacity', 0);
                g.selectAll("polygon")
                    .transition(200)
                    .style("fill-opacity", cfg.opacityArea);
            })
            .append("svg:title")
            .text(function(j) {
                return Math.max(j.value, 0)
            });
        series++;
    });
    //Tooltip
    tooltip = g.append('text')
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .style('font-family', 'sans-serif')
        .style('font-size', '13px');
}

});
```

Regards,
Shekar.

Comment: "Could anybody please help me in resolving this issue." No, we can't. You haven't shown us any of your code, how are we supposed to work out what's wrong with it?

Comment: Hi Chris,.I edited the post and added the code am using.Please check this

Comment: If it is shown but then disappearing, what HTML elements can you see in debugger? Is the container and SVG element available, but height or width attributes are messed up?

Comment: @Shekar, your chart seems to work fine, the chart disappearing may be due to some other code in your application throwing an error.

Comment: I m facing exactly same issue @ShekarMantri,did you find any solution for chart disappearing please let me know!